# How to remove white space between ImageMagick's montage tiles?

Tags: imagemagick, montage

I current have code that build a montage using ImageMagick. This is my line of code:

```
montage -mode Concatenate -tile ${tile} -geometry ${geometry}+0+0 ${input} ${output}
```

I'm using `-label ${label}` to name my labels (in my input var).

This gets me a montage with a lot of white space, like that:

[image]

I checked on the manual and forums but everyone seem to agree that the way to do this is to use concatenate or geometry +0+0. I am already using those and it does not work. I also read that the font should be automatically chosen to fit the free space. Right now, there is way too much white space.

**My goal**: To get the white space (between the tiles on the vertical) to fit the current labels height and nothing more.

If you have an idea, I would be really happy.

Thank you anyway guys!

PS: It also doesn't work without labels. I get:

[image]

PPS: I'm sorry if my english is not really good, I am french from Montréal, Qc, Canada.

---

UPDATE: Those are my settings:

```
tile=4x3
geometry=386x305
```

Comment: Can you expand the `$tile` & `$geometry` variables? As written, the example code does not produce the whitespace in the example images.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot my config. I added it right now on the bottom, under the "UPDATE" title. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The additional white space is coming from your geometry setting. The options `-geometry 386x305+0+0` is adding an additional 15px between the image and the label.

[image: whitespace between image and label]

If you omit the `WxH` and add a non-zero value to the offset `-geometry +0+15`, then you'll have additional white space after the label.

[image: whitepsace after label]

To limit the white space to text height, and nothing more, just keep the option as `-geometry +0+0`.

[image: no whitespace]

> I also read that the font should be automatically chosen to fit the free space.

I think that's reversed. The white space is determined by the typeface of the font. I wouldn't say fonts automatically adjust *<blank>*, but default to *<blank>*. It's always a good idea to define the [font](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#label) & [pointsize](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#pointsize).

Comment: TLDR; `montage in1.jpg in2.jpg -geometry +0+0 out.jpg`